# Apache Kafka Topic Security

Tags: apache-kafka

I have listeners configured with 2 ports as below:

```
(9092 -> Plaintext, 9092 -> SASL_PLAIN)
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092, SASL_PLAIN://:9093
```

For a topic, I want restrict Consumers to consume data from 9093 port only, and consuming data from 9092 port should be denied.

I've gone through ACL concept, but haven't seen an option to restrict Consumer pulling data from non-secure port (in this case- 9092)

How can this be configured?

Answer (score 1):

Just give to your users the hostnames of your Kafka brokers with port 9093 as the bootstrap servers, for example: `192.168.0.1:9093, 192.168.0.2:9093`.

When they'll use that to bootstrap their Kafka client, the brokers will only advertise the listener the connection used. It does not advertise all listeners. The Metadata clients will receive will only contain 9093 in this example.

Then using your firewall restrict port 9092 to only allow trusted IPs. This will prevent malicious/badly-configured clients to connect on this port.

Also note that SASL_PLAINTEXT is not secure as credentials (username and password) are exchanged in plaintext over the network. SASL_SSL should be used for real deployments.

Comment: Hi Michael,
Thanks for your suggestion. 
Instead of using firewall restriction on port 9092, is there an option to have the 9092 port blocked for a particular topic ?

Comment: You could build a custom PrincipalBuilder (`principal.builder.class`) that adds to the principal the security protocol and then have a custom Authorizer (`authorizer.class.name`) block access to a topic based on the security protocol. But if you don't already have these in place it's quite a bit of work. For your simple use case, a firewall rule seems easier